# Creating surface area regions of minimum size from raster file using ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, surface

I have these in a raster of Ontario province in Canada (both tiled and mosaiced versions) in ArcGIS

Also I have a list of dam sites. I created buffer zones around these sites, now I want to generate potential sites of plane areas (with low elevation distance between points of each area). Basically the output should be a shapefile with all these polygons for potential sites.

I am new to ArcGIS and GIS in general, all the examples and questions I see they already have shapefiles with sites... what *emphasized text* I need is to generate a shapefile with potential sites with a minimum area.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is the [Raster Calculator](http://resources.arcgis.com/EN/HELP/MAIN/10.1/index.html#//009z000000zn000000). With a well built expression you can get all the areas you want. A little more help [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1h_C8dIc4XI).
When you finished you should get a binary map, with the result areas and everything else. You can convert this with the [raster to polygon](http://resources.arcgis.com/EN/HELP/MAIN/10.1/index.html#//001200000008000000) tool.